# Find all real solutions $x$ for the equation $x^{1/2} − (2−2x)^{1/2} = 1$

Tags: functions, arithmetic, real-numbers

This is what the answer says:

Note that the equation can be rewritten as $\sqrt{x} − \sqrt{2 − 2x} = 1$,

and the existence of such real $x$ implies that $x$ is larger than or equal to $0$ and $x$ is less than or equal to $1$, since we implicitly assume that $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{2 − 2x}$ are real as well. Then

$\sqrt{x} − \sqrt{2 − 2x} < \sqrt{1} = 1 \text{ if } x < 1$, and

$\sqrt{x} − \sqrt{2 − 2x} = 1 \text{ if } x = 1$.

Thus, $x = 1$ is the only real solutions of the equation $\sqrt{x} − \sqrt{2 − 2x} = 1$.

---

I don't understand how

$\sqrt{x} − \sqrt{2 − 2x} < \sqrt{1} = 1  \text{ if }  x < 1$.

I understand everything else.

Can someone please explain? Thank you.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2-2x} \leq \sqrt{x}$

Comment: Ohh because if x is less than 1 then root x is less than root 1 and since the equation is root x minus something it must be less than root x so it must also be less than root 1!

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: But how does that mean x = 1 is the solution when equation is less than 1?

Comment: You showed that if $x<1$ then x is not a solution. But if $x=1$ you just need to check

Comment: ??? I don't understand... x is not a solution? where did that come from?

Comment: You just showed that $x<1$ implies that $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-2x} <1$...

Comment: How does that mean x < 1 is not a solution...?

Comment: ohhhh wait we have to show that the equation equals to 1 and since if x is less than 1 the equation does not equal to 1 so x less than 1 is not a solution?

Comment: If it was you would have $1=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-2x} <1$

Comment: And if x = 1 then the equation does equal to 1 so x = 1 is the real solution?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2-2x} \leq \sqrt{x}$. Then if $x<1$ we have $\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{1}=1$. It follows that $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2-2x} <1$ for $x<1$. So if $x<1$ it is not a solution. If $x=1$ we have $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2-2x}=\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{2-2}=1 $. So $x=1$ is a solution

Comment: how does this mean x = 1 is the solution for √x − √(2 − 2x) < 1 ?

Comment: how do we know x < 1 is not a solution?

Comment: $x<1$ implies that $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-2x} <1$. So it can not be a solution of $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-2x} =1$

Comment: Is it because we have to show that the equation equals to 1? Any x that shows this is the solution but the x that shows the equation is not equal to 1, like x less than 1, is not a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2-2x} = 1 \implies x = 1 + 2-2x + 2\sqrt{2-2x} \implies 3x - 3 = \sqrt{2-2x}$$ $$ \implies 9(x^2 - 2x + 1) = 2-2x \implies 9x^2 - 16x +7 = 0 \implies (x -1)(9x - 7) = 0  $$
Thus $ x = 1, \frac{7}{9} $. Now, $$ \sqrt{\frac{7}{9}}-\sqrt{2-\frac{14}{9}} \neq 1 $$
Thus $x=1 $ is the solution.